# Tengo un problema importando una librería a python

Tags: python, web, flask

Quiero hacer una página web, estoy siguiendo un tutorial, en el que usan Flask. Yo estoy usando Visual Studio y por algún motivo cuando pongo:
**from** flask **import** Flask
me dice que no existe la librería flask. La instale igual que en el video y en la consola de comandos me dice que tengo la versión 2.0.1  por lo cual considero que es un problema de Visual Studio más que mala instalación. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: 1. asegúrate de no estar en un entorno virtual (y si lo estas asegúrate de que esté activado)  2. haz `pip show flask` y si ves algo esta todo bien 3. reinicia visual studio

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.